# Plotting two different sized arrays with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, graphviz

I want to use matplotlib to plot my data. I want to have 4 different y values plotted on the same graph so I can compare the 4. Currently, my 'x' data is an array of size 10:

```
x: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and my y data, of 3 values, is:

```
y: [[0.6, 0.3, 0.4], [0.2, 0.5, 0.4], [0.6, 0.3, 0.4], .... etc.]
```

each nested array corresponds to that x value. So for x=1, the different y values are 0.6, 0.3, 0.4.

How can I plot these all together on one graph?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list of lists (y) to a more adequate format before plotting, and use a for loop to plot in the same graph.

Try this example (is basic):

```
def plotting(y):
    new_y = [ [sublist[i] for sublist in y] for i in range(len(y[0])) ]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
    for sublist in new_y:
        x = np.arange(0, len(sublist))
        axes.plot(x, sublist)

    return fig, axes
```

Note that the 1st line into the method creates a new y list.

```
# use
fig, ax = plotting(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` function to transpose your `y`-list, extracting arrays of size equivalent to `x`. For example,

```
y1,y2,y3=list(zip(*y))
```

Then plot each of y1,y2, and y3.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a for loop:

```
for col in np.array(y).T:
    plt.plot(x, col)
```

Run on sample data:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23]
    ]
```

Output:

[image]